# Check if element exists on site's pages using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++){ //счетчик для перебора страниц
let sitepage = 'site.com/' + i; // объявляем переменную, хранящую url страницы, к которой отправляется запрос
}

let response = await (fetch(sitepage), document.getElementById('elem')); //отправляем запрос для поиска нужного элемента на странице номер i

let noelempages = [];// создаем массив, в котором будут сохраняться страницы, не содержащие искомого элемента

if (response = false){ //проверяем результат запроса
noelempages.push(sitepage);// добавляем страницу, на которой отсутствует элемент, к массиву
}
console.log(noelempages);//отправляем массив со страницами, на которых отсутствует элемент, в консоль
```

Выкладывал схожий вопрос, но, как мне верно указали, неконкретно его сформулировал. Данный код почему-то выдает "Uncaught ReferenceError: await is not defined", хотя в спецификации метода fetch указано использование именно этого синтаксиса. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Upd. Сделал как в ответе, данном ниже, и запустил через Tampermonkey. Не работает Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

(async function main() {
  const response = await fetch('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1213490/check-if-element-exists-on-sites-pages-using-fetch');
  const html = await response.text();
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  const element = doc.querySelector('Thor and Jerry');
  console.log(element.innerText);
})();})();
```

Comment: шо сие означает let response = await (fetch(sitepage), getElementById(elem));

Comment: это как я что-то не понимаю let response = await fetch(sitepage) ладно

Comment: getElementById(elem) это чей метод?

Comment: Понял, в getElementById нужны кавычки для id, сейчас добавлю

Comment: >>>шо сие означает let response = await (fetch(sitepage), getElementById(elem)).   ||
       Насколько я понял, так мы отправляем запрос fetch с уточнением того, что на странице нужно найти элемент

Comment: document.getElementById(elem)

Comment: Простите, мне очень стыдно. Исправил

Comment: а на самом деле если ав получили ответ это делается let response = await fetch(sitepage)

Comment: и если хотите там что-то найти. То нужно средствами дом либо икать в резйльтирующей строке нужный вам текст

Comment: То есть напрямую обращаться к элементу в DOM через fetch не получится?

Comment: да не получится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы использовать результат `fetch()` как документ, можно воспользоваться [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
(async function main() {
  const response = await fetch('http://example.com/');
  const html = await response.text();
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  const element = doc.querySelector('p');
  console.log(element.innerText);
})();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, запустил через Tampermonkey. К сожалению, не работает. Подробнее в шапке

Comment: [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) использует CSS-селекторы, в вашем же варианте `'Thor and Jerry'` не похоже на CSS-селектор. Если вы запустите `document.querySelector('Thor and Jerry')` в консоли для этой страницы, ошибка будет та же. Я этот метод просто привёл для примера, вы можете использовать `getElementById`, как планировали, или любой метод для документа или элементов, чтобы проверять, что вам нужно.

Comment: Если же вам нужно проверить, что такого элемента нет, просто проверьте на `null` прежде, чем запрашивать свойство вроде `.innerText`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сработало. Просто я тот еще нуб и сразу вас не понял