# Как правильно зациклить данную функцию?

Tags: javascript, циклы

```
(async function main() { //объявляем асинхронную функцию
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) { //счетчик для перебора страниц
  var sitepage = 'site.com/' + i;} // объявляем переменную, хранящую url страницы, к которой отправляется запрос
const response = await fetch(sitepage);//отправляем запрос, используя в качестве url страницы переменную sitepage
const html = await response.text();//указываем получаемый тип данных
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');//обрабатываем запрос с помощью DOMParser
const element = document.getElementById('elem'); //ищем искомый элемент на странице
let noelempages = []; // создаем массив, в котором будут сохраняться страницы, не содержащие искомого элемента
if (element != null) { //проверяем результат запроса
  noelempages.push(sitepage);} // добавляем url страницы, на которой отсутствует элемент, к массиву

alert(noelempages);// выводим массив на экран
})();
```

Alert упорно выдает только site.com/5, хотя на предыдущих страницах (site.com/1 и т.д. элемент "elem" также присутствует). Понимаю, что скорее всего дело в неправильно заданном цикле. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой цикл здесь лучше использовать? Я перечитал около десяти схожих вопросов здесь, но когда попробовал добавить колбек как здесь [Как последовательно вызвать асинхронную функцию с коллбеками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708781/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) получил зависание devtools.

Comment: такое ощущение, что в вопрос вставлен результат минификации. Попробуй отформатировать данный кол, большая часть твоих ошибок, как раз из-за плохого форматирования тяжело находится

Comment: Плюс не полностью копируешь код из ранее данных ответов, например из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1213744/186999 поэтому и получаешь ошибки дополнительные и трудноуловимые

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, буду форматировать код. Там не минификация, просто я еще не привык к тому, как нужно правильно его оформлять.

Comment: И код теперь буду копировать внимательнее, спасибо за совет.

Comment: Не забывай отмечать галочкой, ответ, который помог решить проблему. Сейчас у тебя из трех отвеченных вопросов ни в одном не проставлен выбранный ответ

Comment: А я все вверх нажимал. Сейчас сделаю.

Comment: Вверх тоже надо :-) и галочки надо

Comment: Хорошо) Просто вверх мне репутация пока не позволяла)

Comment: Кстати установка галочки, добавляет репутацию и автору вопроса

Comment: Да, рейтинг уже вырос)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема заключается в неверном форматировании.

Если отформатировать код, видно, что внутри цикла находится всего одна строчка

```
var sitepage = 'site.com/' + i;
```

Следовательно, последнее значение с `i==5`  и будет использовано в **единственном** запросе.

```js
(async function main() { //объявляем асинхронную функцию
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) { //счетчик для перебора страниц
    var sitepage = 'site.com/' + i;
  } // цикл закончился.

  const response = await fetch(sitepage); //отправляем запрос, используя в качестве url страницы переменную sitepage
  const html = await response.text(); //указываем получаемый тип данных
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html'); //обрабатываем запрос с помощью DOMParser

  /********************************************************/
  // если была идея искать в полученном документе, вместо `document`
  // надо было использовать `doc`, полученный на предыдущем шаге.
  const element = document.getElementById('elem'); //ищем искомый элемент на странице
  /********************************************************/

  let noelempages = []; // создаем массив, в котором будут сохраняться страницы, не содержащие искомого элемента

  if (element != null) { //проверяем результат запроса
    noelempages.push(sitepage);
  } // добавляем url страницы, на которой отсутствует элемент, к массиву

  alert(noelempages); // выводим массив на экран
})();
```

---

Для решения достаточно внести запросы **внутрь** цикла

```js
(async function main() { //объявляем асинхронную функцию
    let noelempages = []; // создаем массив, в котором будут сохраняться страницы, не содержащие искомого элемента

    for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) { //счетчик для перебора страниц
        var sitepage = 'site.com/' + i;

        const response = await fetch(sitepage); //отправляем запрос, используя в качестве url страницы переменную sitepage
        const html = await response.text(); //указываем получаемый тип данных
        const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html'); //обрабатываем запрос с помощью DOMParser

        /********************************************************/
        // если была идея искать в полученном документе, вместо `document`
        // надо было использовать `doc`, полученный на предыдущем шаге.
        const element = document.getElementById('elem'); //ищем искомый элемент на странице
        /********************************************************/

        if (element != null) { //проверяем результат запроса
            noelempages.push(sitepage);
        } // добавляем url страницы, на которой отсутствует элемент, к массиву

    } // цикл закончился.

    console.log(noelempages); // выводим массив на экран
})();
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за уделенное время. Вы решили проблему, над которой я бился целый день. Схема у меня в голове выстраивается, но с реализацией в виде кода проблемы. В будущем уделю особое внимание форматированию, раз с ним у меня такие проблемы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Может так?

```js
(async function main() { //объявляем асинхронную функцию
 let noelempages = []; // создаем массив, в котором будут сохраняться страницы, не содержащие искомого элемента;tn nfr j
  for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) { //счетчик для перебора страниц
    var sitepage = 'site.com/' + i;
    const response = await fetch(sitepage);//отправляем запрос, используя в качестве url страницы переменную sitepage
    const html = await response.text();//указываем получаемый тип данных
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');//обрабатываем запрос с помощью DOMParser
    const element = doc.getElementById('elem'); //ищем искомый элемент на странице
    
    if (element != null) { //проверяем результат запроса
      noelempages.push(sitepage);} // добавляем url страницы, на которой отсутствует элемент, к массиву
  } // объявляем переменную, хранящую url страницы, к которой отправляется запрос
  
  alert(noelempages);// выводим массив на экран
})();
```